# JNI compiling on different platforms

Tags: macos, compiler-construction, java-native-interface, zeromq

I'm trying to compile the 0MQ java JNI binding...
If I compile the jar on mac os x can I copy this to a linux distro?

```
Download jzmq, the java JNI lib for zmq. Uncompress and cd into that dir, and build it:
./autogen.sh  
./configure  
make  
make install  
You'll end up with the zmq.jar in /usr/local/share/java/ and the native lib in /usr/local/lib
```

http://blog.pmorelli.com/getting-zeromq-and-jzmq-running-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear, but JAR files are portable: JNI libraries are not.